Expo-notifications not working on device, but getting token
I'm building an React Native Expo app and trying to get expo-notifications working.  I'm taking code from an existing app that does create push notifications, but for some reason, it's not working with this current build.
In package.json:
"expo-notifications": "^0.27.7"
I have followed the standard implementation:
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
    import * as Device from "expo-device";
    import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
    import Constants from "expo-constants";
    import { Platform } from "react-native";

    export const usePushNotifications = () => {
      Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
        handleNotification: async () => ({
          shouldPlaySound: true,
          shouldShowAlert: true,
          shouldSetBadge: false,
        }),
      });

  // Can use this function below or use Expo's Push Notification Tool from: https://expo.dev/notifications
  async function sendPushNotification(expoPushToken) {
    const message = {
      to: expoPushToken,
      sound: "default",
      title: "Original Title",
      body: "And here is the body!",
      data: { someData: "goes here" },
    };

    await fetch("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(message),
    });
  }

  const [expoPushToken, setExpoPushToken] = useState("");
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState(false);
  const notificationListener = useRef();
  const responseListener = useRef();

  async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
    let token;

    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
        name: "default",
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
      });
    }

    if (Device.isDevice) {
      const { status: existingStatus } =
        await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
      let finalStatus = existingStatus;
      if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
        const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
        finalStatus = status;
      }
      if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
        alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
        return;
      }
      token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
        projectId: Constants.expoConfig?.extra?.eas.projectId,
      });
    } else {
      alert("Must be using a physical device for Push Notifications");
    }

    return token;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then((token) =>
      setExpoPushToken(token)
    );

    notificationListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
        setNotification(notification);
      });

    notificationListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
        setNotification(notification);
      });

    responseListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });

    return () => {
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(
        notificationListener.current
      );
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
    };
  }, []);

  return {
    expoPushToken,
    notification,
  };
};

And then within app.js
  const { expoPushToken } = usePushNotifications();
  console.log("Push Notifications token :", expoPushToken);

So, nothing crazy. Basic setup.
I run the app (npx expo start --dev-client) and run on my iPhone that is registered on my Expo project.  Either using the Expo Notifications page, or running sendPushNotification() using the token I'm getting from the console, everything runs ok (status:200) - but I'm getting nothing to the device.  I've checked that notifications are allowed on the device and device is not silent.
Any advice on triage?
The response I get from the console if I fire the notification from the app:
Notification Response : {"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "B44199F9-59EE-4CD2-9D2E-DC088353524F", "name": "send.json", "offset": 0, "size": 68, "type": "application/json"}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "B44199F9-59EE-4CD2-9D2E-DC088353524F", "name": "send.json", "offset": 0, "size": 68, "type": "application/json"}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"alt-svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000", "content-length": "68", "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8", "date": "Sun, 28 Apr 2024 05:19:26 GMT", "etag": "\"44-qrsRHa9ppS08dGDo3z285YOag10\"", "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains", "vary": "Accept-Encoding, Origin", "via": "1.1 google", "x-content-type-options": "nosniff", "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN"}}, "ok": true, "status": 200, "statusText": "", "type": "default", "url": "https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send"}

Status:200
I've even rebuilt the app (create-expo-app) and copied all code across, just to see if there was something strange going on.  I've also deleted node_modules and yarn install to recreate.
I'm at a loss....
